# How to record statistics for habits with org-habit

Tags: org-mode, logging, org-habit

I've started using `org-habit` this week. I can set my habits and see the nice colored consistency graph to track visually my habits.

However, I would like to have a numeric record of this. For example, something for each habit, I am imagining something like the [statistics cookies](https://orgmode.org/manual/Breaking-Down-Tasks.html):

```
Number of repetitions done / Number of repetitions scheduled 
Percent of repetitions done %
```

Or even better, have some stats about how many repetitions I have done a habit in a row.

This [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/58945/29260) solves the issue with a capture template in a table, but I was wondering if it's possible to do it directly with the `org-habit` module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial solution for the problem.

1. Download this file into your private config:
   https://gitlab.com/OlMon/org-habit-report/-/blob/master/org-habit-report.el
2. Load the file with something like `(load-file "org-habit-report.el")`
3. In the file you need to track your habits, add this dynamic table (change `tstart` and `tend` to any range you want)

```
#+BEGIN: ol/habit-report :tstart "<2021-12-26 Sun>" :tend "<2022-02-28 Mon>" :scope file
#+END:
```

4. Finally, `C-c C-c` to update the table. It should show all your habits with some stats, for example:

```
#+BEGIN: ol/habit-report :tstart "<2020-12-16 Wed>" :tend "<2021-01-31 Sun>" :scope file
#+CAPTION: Habit report from 16-12-20 to 31-01-21
| Heading  | Done Count | Missed Count | Last Missed      | Longest Streak (days) | Longest Streak (done) | Currently longest |
|----------|------------|--------------|------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|-------------------|
| Jogging1 |         23 |            3 | <2021-01-30 Sat> |                    25 |                    10 | nil               |
| Jogging2 |         23 |            3 | <2021-01-30 Sat> |                    25 |                    10 | nil               |
| Workout  |         10 |            0 | nil              |                    48 |                    10 | t                 |
#+END:
```

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged (the link disappears and the answer becomes completely useless). Can you add some details about how to use the package? Thx!

Comment: Thanks! I edited the answer to explain better the workflow with this code.